# WinRM - Error 1297: How to give a local user the needed privileges to run Win RM service?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, winrm

I'm using WinRM on EC2 Instances (Windows 10) to start Jeknins-Pipelinejobs at those instances (jenkins ec2-plugin). In my Pipelinefiles, i have some commands/Tools which use the current user to authenticate at a webservice.

Since the WinRM service is running as the local NETWORK account, the authentication failed. This is why I like to run the WinRM service with another user. This user is part of the local administrator group.
When I now try to start the Win RM service, I get following error:

```
WinRM windows could not start the service on local computer Error:1297 A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration.
```

In the windows event log, following error is logged:

```
The Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) service failed to start due to the following error: 
A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration.
```

What privilege is needed for my local user to run the Win RM service?

Thanks for your help!